# How to develop a web UI for Apache Solr

Tags: javascript, html, apache, solr, frontend

I'm trying to develop a simple web-based search prototype on a list of documents. I've learnt about `Apache Solr` recently. Its simple REST APIs looks promising. However, I couldn't find any tutorial on how to develop an easy-to-use Web UI client on top of that. I also had problems indexing file types of `PDF`, `XLS`, and other types.

I'm new to web development. Is there any open-source javascript/HTML client on how to use Apache Solr as a starting point? Maybe how to implement `autocomplete` features, index files, get search results, etc. Any hints would be useful for a starter.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, check the [Running solr](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/running-solr.html) documentation section. Default solr installation contains a lot of pre-configured request and update handlers. You can play with it using solr Admin Console. It provides GUI to build queries. So, you will get an idea what parameters you can use and how.

Update.

Try to do this

```
cd <solr instalation directory>
bin/solr start
bin/solr create -c files -d example/files/conf
bin/post -c files ~/Documents
```

After this you can open http://localhost:8983/solr/#/files/query and push "execute query" button to see a list of indexed files

Comment: Yes I know all these. Does it work only with pre-structured documents (e.g. xml, csv, json)? I want to enter text files, pdf files, ... and simply find most *related* document for that. But it doesn't work like that.

Comment: You can index literally any containing text files.  Check the <solr_instalation_dir>/example/files to see how to do this, see README.txt for instructions.